# backbutton event not firing in cordova windows phone app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to test my cordova app which has been built using Intel XDK for windows phone.

I am testing the app in windows phone 8.1 emulator, the backbutton event  is not firing, instead it exits the app.

And I tried with some suggestions I read from internet to use winjs to capture backclick event which is not also working.

Please help me resolve this problem.

Code to capture backbutton:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
 // Code to handle;
 e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

With WinJS:

```
window.WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function (e) {
 // Code to handle

 e.handled = true;
 return true;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In WinJS, make sure you are calling the onbackclick function within the onDeviceReady function.

Try this sample code:

```
if (device.platform == "windows") {
    // Get the back button working in WP8.1
    WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function () {
        onBackKeyDown();
        return true; // This line is important, without it the app closes.
    }
}
else {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
```

Then just define what you would like to do on back button press with a onBackKeyDown function.

```
function onBackKeyDown(eventArgs) {
   eventArgs.handled = true;
   /* Your behaviour/navigation */
}
```

Comment: Hi Tobiah, I tried this already, it does not work. Is there anything else I am missing

Comment: @SamDeepak what happens when you press the back button? Does it back out of the app, or does your expected behavior not happen? Can you post your code so we can see what could be wrong?

Comment: HI Tobiah, I posted intel forum where I used to ask questions, as per them, they referred a compatibility fix between windows phone 8.x and cordova. You can read here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/606709. Now it works. Thanks for heads up.